# [Mobile][Automation] How to capture mobile network traffic for mobile app when tapping on different sections

Tags: javascript, mobile, automation, webdriver-io, charles-proxy

I am developing mobile automation framework, I got a requirement to capture network traffic of various API call when tapping on different sections of our app.
Basically, these network calls (API call) are used to verify application usage and generate analytics report to define future product development strategy.
I am using WebDriverIO with Appium for mobile UI automation. To verify this API call manually my team is using charles proxy.
I am exploring few options to automate this task but if you have any proven solution then please do share. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Webdriver.io already support this feature: https://webdriver.io/docs/proxy/#proxy-between-browser-and-internet

They expose an API using https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy which is a proven solution for network capturing for mobile automation.